# Is there a better way to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using React. On click of a <kbd>button</kbd>, the following function is executed:

```
const completeTaskHandler = (idValue) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
        const updatedData = [...prevData];
        const updatedItem = updatedData.filter((ele) => ele.id === idValue)[0];
        updatedItem.completed = true;
        const newData = updatedData.filter((ele) => ele !== updatedItem);
        newData.unshift(updatedItem);
        return newData;
    });
};
```

My data is an array of objects like this:

`[{userId: 1, id: 2, title: "task 1", completed: true}, .....]`.

Basically I want to move the updated item to the start of the array. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: does this code work? what do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: code does work. Looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updatedItem` should not be mutated. And this string `const newData = updatedData.filter((ele) => ele !== updatedItem);` is not fine. You can do it like this :

```
const completeTaskHandler = (idValue) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      const targetItem = prevData.find((ele) => ele.id === idValue);
      const updatedItem = { ...targetItem, completed: true };
      const filteredData = prevData.filter((ele) => ele.id !== idValue);
      return [updatedItem, ...filteredData];
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better to reducing an extra filter:

```
const completeTaskHandler = (idValue) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      const targetIndex = prevData.findIndex((ele) => ele.id === idValue);
return [{ ...prevData[targetIndex], completed: true }].concat(prevData.slice(0, targetIndex + 1)) .concat(
 prevData.slice(targetIndex + 1) 
)
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

First find index of updated element using `Array.findIndex()`, then remove the same element using `Array.splice()` and add it to front of the array.

```
const completeTaskHandler = (idValue) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
        const updatedData = [...prevData];
        const index = updatedData.findIndex(obj => obj.id === idValue);
        const [updatedItem] = updatedData.splice(index, 1);
        updatedItem.completed = true;
        updatedData.unshift(updatedItem);
        return updatedData;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one with only one `forEach`.

```
const completeTaskHandler = idValue => {
    setData(prevData => {
      let updatedItem = {}, newData = [];
      prevData.forEach((ele) => {
          if (ele.id === idValue) {
             updatedItem = ele;
             updatedItem.completed = true;      
          } else {
            newData.push(ele);
          }          
      });     
      newData.unshift(updatedItem);
      return newData;
    });
  };
```